# Is ConcurrentDictionary, a "concurrent" version of SortedList?

Tags: c#, concurrency, sortedlist, concurrentdictionary

I would like to understand the Computational Complexity of a [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) vers [`SortedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) (Which is `O(logarithmic(n))`), is a ConcurrentDictionary just a concurrent synchronized  implementation of a `SortedList`? or do these data structures vary? among one another?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConcurrentDictionary<T,U>` is a concurrent version of a `Dictionary<T,U>`.  It does not sort by keys like a `SortedList<T,U>`.  The complexity is closely related to a `Dictionary<T,U>`'s complexity, so fetches approach O(1).

`SortedList<T,U>` has O(log n) complexity for most fetch operations since it's walking the internal sorted structure.

Comment: Is there anyway to achieve `O(log n)` with a Concurrent Data Structure?

Comment: @Killrawr `O(1)` typically is better - why are you trying to achieve `O(log n)`?

Comment: I thought `O(log n)` searching was faster than `O(n)`, from my understanding its like searching a text book and cutting the book in half each iteration till the result is found. Instead of searching each page of the book until the result is found.

Comment: @Killrawr `O(log n)` is usually faster than `O(n)`, esp. for large values of N.  This is `O(1)` (constant time), though,  not `O(n)` (linear time), which is typically the best option of any, as it doesn't change as you add more items.

Comment: @Killrawr In your analogy, it's like being able to instantly open up to page 3734 in your book *without* having to scan pages at all...

Comment: thanks, I was referring to the analogy given on [CS50](http://cs50.tv/2011/fall/) (14:00-17:28). I'll admit though I probably didn't explain it as well as CS50.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` is a thread-safe analog of `Dictionary<K,V>` and both should have complexity *O(1)*. They don't provide key sorting, order is not guaranteed.

Comment: It's more accurate to say `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` is a *concurrent* version of `Dictionary`, to distinguish it from other *thread-safe* implementations, such as those that use exclusive locking (`lock(this) { ... }`) inside the methods.

Comment: @280Z28: I purposely checked [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and it describes it as: "Represents a **thread-safe** collection of key/value pairs that can be accessed by multiple threads concurrently".

Comment: I should add that I didn't down vote you, and you aren't incorrect. I was simply pointing out that the other answer given is ever-so-slightly more specific. :)

Comment: @280Z28 That is a bit of a nit-pick.  It is a fully thread-safe implementation.  It is mostly lockless, vs using a monitor-based synchronization mechanism, but it is still a "thread-safe analog of Dictionary" in my opinion...

Comment: @ReedCopsey when two nearly-equivalent correct answers are given, nitpicking is allowed :)