# Working with very large Dictionary<> in C#

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, search, large-data

I am implementing a type of search (TF-IDF) in which every word has a score calculated that is proportional to all the documents being searched. I have 100GB of documents to search.

If I was working with 1GB of documents, I would use:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Document>>
```

..where `string` is the word and `List<Document>` is all documents, ranked in order, containing that word. This does not scale up. I am using a `Dictionary<>` because lookup time is O(1) (in theory).

My intended solution is a SQLServer database in which words are listed in a table, with the relevant List object stored serialized. My concern is that reading the DB and rebuilding to `List<>` each time will be very inefficient.

Am I going in the wrong direction here? What is a normal solution to working with huge dictionaries?

Comment: I would consider a disk-backed storage mechanism: see the various Hash/Hierarchial "NoSQL" options.

Comment: I'll let others answer your question, but let me suggest using MongoDB for this solution. It was created with exactly this type of thing in mind. There is a .net driver for it, and it works much the same way as entity framework.

Answer (score 8):

You are right in saying that using a `List` would be inefficient, on average a `List` would achieve linear output (`O(n)`).

Personally, I would use a `Concurrent Dictionary` which is guaranteed to be [`O(1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511394/is-concurrentdictionary-a-concurrent-version-of-sortedlist). During one of the project's I've worked on I was working with large files 100MB text files and I found a `Concurrent Dictionary` could sufficiently sort and search information completing an estimated 10,000ish give or take records every second.

Have a look at this neat [cheat sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/). for Big-Oh algorithms it provides some neat details for best and worse case scenarios. When dealing with massive data sets its important to keep the concepts of `Abstraction` and `Decomposition` in mind.

> **Abstraction** Concentrate on the most important elements - ignore irrelevant details

Only store information that is important, I highly doubt you will need an entire 1GB file to be in memory.

> **Decomposition** Divide and Conquer

Ensure the desktop running your application has a good latency to your database. I would recommend only storing what you need in memory and using LINQ to retrieve only the exact information you need, once you have the information that is relevant to your task... you can then filter it further.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look at that data structure. My basic problem still stands though; storing 100GB in memory / virtual memory is infeasible.

Comment: If my answer helped solve your issues, I'd appreciate if you marked it as the correct answer. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is not an issue, I would use your code. If the list is a performance issue, make that a dictionary also. Saving things in DB is fine, because it is fast and don't need a lot of memory.

It is just a question of intuition. My choice would be database and good indexes. Call the database everytime. If performance is critical save it in memory like you did and replace list with dictionary somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you, I have ever done a task like yours, but my data was much less than yours. I think dictionary is useful for your word search and its revelant documents, as it could keep the word's relationship with the documents, and you could easily query and sort words. about your concern, I think reading the DB and rebuilding to List<> is not inefficient, but if you rebuild and update the list very frequently, maybe you need to optimize that by other ways, such as file cache in server disk, not to frequently update long text value to database.
good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I am only touching on how you should store/retrieve the data. I would try something like Dictionary<string, List> where List holds the ids of the documents you are referring to. Your database would have a Word table a WordToDocument table and a Document table.

If you are building a website there is no reason to return the entire contents of every document. You would only need to return the name of the documents as a user could them select the document they would like to read.